# API access to Google Analytics Content Grouping dimensions?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Does anyone know if it is possible to access the Google Analytics Content Grouping dimensions via the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works now, you can see here in the Dimensions & Metrics Reference:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=content_grouping

Answer (score 2):

No, don't think you can yet.

It's not listed on their Dimensions & Metrics Reference
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

Comment: confirmed this is correct:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-analytics-data-export-api/9DofC2OxyWc